# python, from json object (hex) to raw internal binary string

Tags: python, json, hex, binary-data

in python how can i convert a "json-loaded" object value into raw binary string? ie "0A" to be converted to "1010"?

what i do is the following:
read a line from a file, ie assume the file contains this line:

```
{"hex":"0A01145af1ab"}
```

i read it with 
then i load it with json library //ok so far

```
data = json.loads(a_line)
```

then i can use data["hex"],

but i need ie. "0A" to be converted to "1010", and i don't know how to do that
i read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445447/in-python-how-to-convert-a-hex-ascii-string-to-raw-internal-binary-string) which is similar to my problem, but it didn't help me (base64.b16decode(data["hex"]) returns error)

thanks a lot!

Comment: `bin(int(data['hex'][:2], 16))`

Comment: @JBernardo -- you get the win.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> bin(int(data['hex'][:2], 16))[2:]
'1010'
```

also `format(..., 'b')` to conver to binary (without the `0b` prefix)